# Kick all members of a guild except members with a role

Tags: discord, discord.js

In my Discord bot, I'm trying to develop a "lockdown mode", where the owner and 3 admins send a bot-generated code to trigger a lockdown, where all members of the server except moderators and the bot are kicked. I have the first part done, now I just need a way to kick everyone in the server except those with a specific role. I can get the role ID, that's not a problem, I just need the code for kicking everyone except a role.

Thanks,
MrConorAE

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can kick everyone from a guild (barring very small guild sizes) in the manner you propose, would be to delete the guild entirely.

There is no way you can achieve kicking large amounts of members within a small period of time, as such an action would spam the Discord API, and result in the termination of your bot.

The best way I could see a 'lockdown mode' being achieved would be to have to bot change the permissions of the general role of your server (whether it is `everyone` or a `Members` role) to have permissions to do nothing in you server, and to view none of the channels. This is the only way I could see this result being achieved in a somewhat non-API-spammy way, but to simply kick everyone from the guild, is a task not achievable on a server that has more than ~10 members.

Comment: That's quite a good idea, but ideally I'd like to keep the server/guild. The roles idea is pretty good, how would you go about that? I understand `member.setRoles()` will work if we have _one_ member, but what about getting all members?

Comment: Again, depending on guild size, it still might not be ideal. Essentially you'd have to fetch all the members, then run a loop to remove/set their roles. Loops that interact with API will 99% of the time be over the rate limits if you try to do it quickly. You could add a delay between each role removal action, but the overall action would take a fair amount of time to complete. @MrConorAE